# Add IDE property run.processes.with.pty to a specific project in CLion

Tags: project, clion

Is it possible to add an `idea.properties` file to a project, so if the project is loaded in CLion the IDE settings are changed, and after closing the project the default settings are restored?

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve by changing this specific property?

Comment: i call a javabackend that draws gui objects if i click on the run button in clion the main routin is started after it's finished Clion stops also the gui process but i don't want that.

Comment: Your title is much more specific than your actual question. Also, this might be a better fit for [su].